# GPS hardware requirements and custom download link

Tags: android, gps-time

I have 2 unrelated questions in one so please bear with me.

I want to know if an Android device absolutely requires a simm card inorder to execute all things Location Based Services.

And ...

I would like friends of mine to download my samlpe app. Is there anyway to put my app online where friends can download and help me test and not put my beta-code on Market place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question, take a look at this question and answer: [Signing an app, but not publishing on Android market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947903/signing-an-app-but-not-publishing-on-android-market)

You'd be publishing as an "unknown source" and your friends' would have to change a setting on their phones.  ATT doesn't allow this on some phones I think.